# jQuery .each() - how to iterate over items and animate each of them separately causing ripple effect

Tags: jquery, animation

I have a page with 100 boxes stacked on top of each other, in a teetering stack.  I want to simulate this teetering with some jQuery animation having them sway back and forth in a ripple effect.

I first tried this:

```
$("#teetering-tester").click(function () {
    $("#box-stack div").each(function (id) {
        $(this).animate({ 'margin-right': "+=3px" }, 300 + id, function () {
            $(this).animate({ 'margin-right': "-=3px" }, 300 + id);
        });
    });
    return false;
});
```

But this makes the entire stack move to the right, and then move to the right.

I was hoping for a ripple effect.  So, I tried to open new threads with setTimeout():

```
$("#doTeeter").click(function () {
    $("#output").append("<li>Starting</li>");
    $("#box-stack div").each(function (id) {
        setTimeout($(this).animate({ 'margin-right': "+=3px" }, 300 + id, function () {
            $(this).animate({ 'margin-right': "-=3px" }, 300 + id);
        }), 700, function () {
            $("#output").append("<li>I'm done</li>");
        });
    });
    return false;
});
```

Same thing- entire stacks moves in unison.

I then tried:

```
$("#doTeeter").click(function () {
    $("#box-stack div").each(function (id) {
        setTimeout(teeterStack(id), 700);
    });
    return false;
});

... 

function teeterStack(id) {
    $("#box-stack div").eq(id)
        .animate({ 'margin-right': "+=3px" }, 500 + id, function () {
            $(this).animate({ 'margin-right': "-=3px" }, 300 + id);
        });
    });
}
```

but they all still move together.

How can I make a ripple effect across my 100 boxes?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,
Scott

### Update

Oh, I just noticed that I'd tried to add some variability by making the animation duration be a function of 300ms plus the id of the item.

### Update 2

I just tried this, and it kinda works, but is a bit herky-jerky:

```
function teeterStack(id) {
    $("#box-stack div").eq(id)
        .animate({ 'margin-right': "+=3px" }, getTime(id), function () {
            $(this).animate({ 'margin-right': "-=3px" }, getTime(id));
        });
}
function getTime(id) {
    var min = 300, max = 2000, step = (max-min)/100;
    return (step*id) + min;
}
```

But I didn't know about delay() so I'm going to give that a shot.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The trick is to delay the start of effect based on the elements index.  Here's an untested poke at it. NOTE: using your first example.

```
$("#teetering-tester").click(function () {
    $("#box-stack div").each(function (id) {

        var stallFor = 300 * parseInt(id); // 300 is the gap between delays, tweek it based on visual preference

        $(this).delay(stallFor).animate({ 'margin-right': "+=3px" }, function () {
            $(this).animate({ 'margin-right': "-=3px" });
        });
    });
    return false;
});
```

#### Suggestion

I'd use `index` instead of `id`.  It's confusing as to what the variable represents.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have the right idea with setTimeout, but the problem is that you're using the same value for the timeout time.  Provide a random (or semi random) value for the second argument of the setTimeout function to get the effect you want.  Assuming the IDs are sequential numbers, I'd suggest something like `setTimeout(teeterStack(id), 700+(id*100));`

Note: I haven't tested this...